# How does Flash and socket connections work on the web?

Tags: flash, sockets, networking, tcp

I am trying to debug a socket connection issue between flash in a web browser and flash in a client type program. The connection is closing properly in the web, so I would like to understand how the web side of things work.

Right now I can load up a remote flash file in a web browser and that triggers a connection ESTABLISHED stat when viewing with netstats -fn. When I close the dialog which runs some javascript to remove the flash from the dom, the connection stats goes to TIME_WAIT.

Does the act of removing the flash from the html DOM sever the flash connection which triggers a TIME_WAIT state? How does that process work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using flash.net.Socket, observe the behavior of calling [socket.close()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html#close%28%29) manually. It's up to the Flash runtime (as it's a fully binary plugin separate from the browser) how to close sockets.

The TIME_WAIT state is part of your computer's networking stack. When you actively close a socket, it goes into the TIME_WAIT state.

> TIME-WAIT - represents waiting for enough time to pass to be sure the
>   remote TCP received the acknowledgment of its connection termination
>   request.

[image: connection states]

Comment: Nice diagram :) Would you know if stripping out the flash <object> and <embed> object from the DOM in an html page would trigger a socket close from a remote flash? Is the connection established by loading a remote swf constant? So if the flash gets removed from an html page the connection is severed.

Comment: that actually depends on the browser - and how (or even whether) the browser unloads the SWF plugin if you remove a swf object from the page.