# IE flash web sockets don't get closed on server reboot

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, sockets, tomcat, websocket

I'm experiencing strange behaviour of the flash web socket implementation which is designed to work in the IE9, but unfortunately it's basic functionality seems not be working in accordance with [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

Let me describe this in details:

On the client side I'd like to know if web socket get closed or not. Well, I do almost in all cases but one - when server is unexpectedly went offline (graceless reboot, crash, outage, etc). It happens only when I use IE and it's [flash web socket implementation](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js). Other browsers behave as they should.

I tried to dig deepper and found out, that during handshake there is no `101 Switching Protocols` recieved on the client side (though it should in accordance with RFC and there are such a requests recieved from server in cases I use another browsers).

I wonder if it is the thing, which prevent client from closing web socket or there are some tricks to do this.

Thanks you all in advance for any help!

p.s. Not sure if it is important but still: on server side for web socket support I use tomcat 7 and it's web socket implementation.

Comment: Just to be clear, it's not "IE's flash web socket implementation", it's *someone's attempt to implement websockets using Flash*. While it's not likely related, how specifically did you conclude that there's no `101 Switching Protocols` message? How specifically are you trying to check whether the socket is closed?

Comment: @EricLaw, Well, I concluded that there is no `101 Switching protocol` just by looking at the incoming http requests in the network tab of the IE. And I conluded that the socket is not closed by checking that onclose event was not fired on the client side. Maybe, I miss something.

Comment: The Network tab in IE cannot show socket-level traffic sent by a Flash applet, as it doesn't go through the interfaces that IE is monitoring.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Flash and socket connections work on the web?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677680/how-does-flash-and-socket-connections-work-on-the-web)